# Copy element of matrix to a vector MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, mapping

Assume we have a matrix A (2x5), with the first row containing the numbers:

```
1 2 3 5 7
```

and the second row:

```
0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2
```

Also, there is a 10 dimensional vector B with numbers 1,2,3...10. 
How can I create a new 10 dimensional vector C that will only contain the values of A (second row) when A(1,:) == B, else 0.

So the new vector C should have the form:

```
0.4 0.1 0.2 0 0.1 0 0.2 0 0 0
```

(add zero for the cells of B that are not in A).

I tried this solution but I have a problem due to the difference in dimensions between A and B.

```
for i=1:53
    if B(i) == A(1,i)
        C{1,i} = A(2,i);
    else
        C{1,i}=0;
    end
end
```

*Index exceeds matrix dimensions.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear what you're after, but this at least gives the desired output:

```
A = [1 2 3 5 7; 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2];
B = 1:10;
[tf,loc] = ismember(A(1,:), B);
C = zeros(1,10);
C(loc(tf)) = A(2,tf)
```

[I'm assuming you mean 10 *element* vector, rather than 10 *dimensional*...]

If you just want to use the first row of `A` as indices and the second row as assigned values, then you don't need to use `B` at all and you can do something like this:

```
A = [1 2 3 5 7; 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2];
C = zeros(1,10);
C(A(1,:)) = A(2,:)
```

Comment: The second answer is wrong since you're treating the A values as indices for C, whereas they need to be treated as values against C, e.g. using this answer `A = [2 3 5 7 11; 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2]` will be ended up `[0 0.4 0.1 0 0.2 0 0.1 0 0 0 0.2] which has 11 dimensions. Also, if you change the elements order of A(1,:), it will produce different results!

Comment: @hmofrad - As I said clearly before the second answer: "If you just want to use the first row of A as indices and the second row as assigned values ..." The question was not very clear, hence both answers.

Answer (score 2):

How about removing the `for loop` and do it inline using `ismember` function:

```
A = [1 2 3 5 7; 0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2];
B = 1:10;
C = zeros(1,10);
C(B(ismember(B, A(1,:)))) = A(2,ismember(A(1,:),B));
```

Hint: Even if we happen to have a value in `A(1,:)` which `B` does not have, this solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ismember` and a `for` loop:

```
clc; clear;

A=[
    1 2 3 5 7;
    0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2
  ];

B = 1:10;

C = zeros(1,10);
for j = 1:10
    if ismember(j, A(1,:))
            C(j) = A(2, A(1,:) == j);
    else
        C(j) = 0;
    end
end
C
```